# Find ratio of ctc of job family in percentage by india and international

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have data table as:

```
            ctc       job_family   country   city
            12000     service       india     delhi
            15000     management    australia  melbourne
            16000     it executive  india      delhi
            16000     service       india      jaipur
            14000     management    australia  sydney
            10000     Billing       canada     Toronto
            20000     Billing       canada     montreal
            15000     service       canada     toronto
            18000     Billing       india      pune
            22000     it executive  india      pune
            20000     Billing       india      mumbai
            12000     management    india      delhi
            14000     management    india      noida
            19000     management    canada     toronto
            19000     management    canada     montreal
```

Now i want ratio of  ctc of each service type internationally to india.
example:
desired output

```
             ratio      job_family     country  
              0.78       Billing       canada
              1.11       management    australia
              1.46       management    canada
```

Beacause Billing total ctc of canada is 30000 and ctc for billing in india is 38000 so ratio is 0.78
Management ctc total in australia is 29000 and in india is 26000 so ratio is 1.11
Management total is 38000 in canada and in india is 26000 so ratio is 1.46

How would I write such SQL query for SQL Server?
I am unable to fine ctc for each category for india beacause group by clause cannot be used in subquery.

Comment: Why are you not returning service/Canada?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select job_family, country,
       sum(ctc) * 1.0 / sum(case when country = 'India' then sum(ctc) end) over (partition by job_family) as ratio
from t
group by job_family, country;
```

Note:  This returns the values for India as well.  If you want to remove those, you can this as a subquery and filter in the outer query.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e3750457351f9d218a08a57682e6c280) is a db<>fiddle.